# Installation Nvidia Gpu Driver dpkg-divert: error:

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, dpkg, gpu-driver

I am installing Nvidia driver 340 in ubuntu 18.04 but i got this error

```
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib' with
different file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1', not allowed
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not use the binaries downloaded from Nvidia. You can install it directly from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Same thing happened sir i run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` still I got this dpkg error

Comment: It may not solve it but try `sudo apt purge Nvidia*` to clean up and then autoinstall or directly at Additional Drivers.

Comment: Have you fixed the problem? I'm facing the same problem.